# How can I show the CPU temperature in the GNOME panel?

Tags: gnome, panel, temperature

I'm looking for a way to show my CPU-temperature in the GNOME 3 Panel in Ubuntu 10.10.
I found a Screen on extensions.gnome.org :

[image: https://extensions.gnome.org/static/extension-data/screenshots/screenshot_231_2.png]

Is there an applet or something like that?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you looking for a Gnome3 extension or something to use in Ubuntu 10.10? Your question is confusing because 10.10 did not contain Gnome3. Please edit your question to explain exactly what your you require help with.

Answer (score 8):

Try installing this extension for GNOME. It is called "Freon."

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/841/freon/

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is. It is called `psensor`. Install it (`apt install psensor`), and run it. It should pop up a window with tempratures:

[image]

Go to preferences, and configure it to start at startup, and only enable the panel icon:

[image]

You might want to fiddle with other settings as well. In the end you should have this:

[image]
(The little thermometer at the left.)

CPU, GPU, motherboard, and hdd temp sources are available. Make sure you have the `sensors` package installed.

The reason I added this answer to a question about a 10 year old Ubuntu is that it pops up at the first page of google searches for *disk temperature in system tray ubuntu*. Tested in 18.04.

Answer (score 3):

try this extension [system-monitor](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/120/system-monitor/) you can choose the information to display like memory, cpu, temperature, etc..

Comment: Thank you, is there an option to move the temperature indicator.Next to the Brightness Control?

Comment: There is an extension but has not yet been updated to gs 3.6